# Installing LTS 18.04.3 on MacBook Pro 2012

Tags: boot, usb, macbook, macbook-pro

I am having some issues installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my 2012 MacBook Pro. My hard drive failed recently while using Mac OS and I would like to switch to using Ubuntu. I have bought a new SSD and am looking to install a stable version of Ubuntu 18.04.3.

I made a live USB to use for the installation, and as a test as to whether my system would be able to run Ubuntu at a good speed or not. When I am running Ubuntu off the live USB, it seems to be really quite fast and responsive. After running the installation and installing it on my SSD, it really begins to slow down and the issues don't end there. My installation has problems with the filesystem, it frequently needs reformatting after every reboot using the command `fsck`.

I tried running a software update after the installation:

```
$: apt-get update
```

This seemed to improve performance slightly. However the problems only got worse after a few reboots, it became slower and slower to use, and the disk would need constant fixing using `fsck`. There would also be issues with shutting down, sometimes the shutdown would be interrupted with error messages saying that the filesystem had become read only.

Is there a set of key things I need to do to get a stable Linux on my 2012 MacBook pro, beyond just installing the distribution off of the live USB?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the disk controller.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the disk controller? I was thinking of trying a new hard drive cable because I've read that apple did have a dodgy run of hard drive cables.

Comment: Maybe it's the cable. The controller can't be replaced apart fom the MB.

Comment: Blimey okay, thank you for the advice. If the cable doesn't sort it out, I'll have a look into getting a new MB installed.

Comment: I replaced my hard drive cable this evening and it seems to have sorted it. The install was about 10x faster and I've rebooted a fair few times now and it's been performing normally. No crashes or disk corruptions.